# XPath Filter by Date

Tags: java, xpath, predicate

I need to filter the records by date through JAVA class:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME = "DateTime"
Date dateNow = setTimeToZero(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String date = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(dateNow);
Request request = table.createRequest();

DATE_FILTER = XPathFilter.newFilter("date-greater-than(" + Root_Table_DateField.format() + '$date')");

request.setXPathFilter(DATE_FILTER);
request.setXPathParameter(DATE_TIME, date);

RequestResult = reqResult = request.execute();
```

The field I am trying to access is define as DateTime, but I don't want the time now, so I set the time to zero, so I can filter for all field with date greater than dd-MM-yyyT00:00:00:000

But it return a predicate error: PredicateException: Invalid XPath expresion ./dateTime = 26-06-2020T00:00:00:000 - Unexpected 'T00:00:00.000'

Any clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the date formatted like that `(xs:date("2020-06-26Z")`

```
date-greater-than(xs:date("2004-12-25-12:00"), (xs:date("2020-06-26Z"))
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/

Comment: I was almost there: the configuratoin of the xpath should be

date-greater-than(path to the field, $PARAMETER)

So, what I did you make it work was do it with a predicate in an XPath static:
StringBuilder predicate = new StringBuilder();
predicate.append("date-greater-than(")
predicate.append(Path.To.Field.format());
predicate.append(", $");
predicate.append(DATE_PARAMETER);
predicate.append());

DATE_FILTER = XPathFilter.newFilter(true, predicate.toString());

Then on another static I called the DATE on a Request and execute the request.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. Glad to see you could figure it out!